# why Javascript function wont apply to element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hover, tablerow

I have this structure for one of my pages:

```
head  
    script  
   /script  
/head  
body  
    table1  
    table2  
/body
```

here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( function() {
      $('tr').click( function() {
         $(this).parents('table').find('tr').each( function( index, element ) {
              $(element).removeClass('selected');
         } );
         $(this).addClass('selected');
         $(this).removeClass('normal');
      } );
    } );
    $( function() {
      $('tr').hover( function() {
         $(this).addClass('highlight');
         $(this).removeClass('normal');
      } );
    } );
    $( function() {
        if($('tr').hasClass('selected')) {
        }
        else {
          $('tr').mouseout( function() {
             $(this).removeClass('highlight');
          } );        
        }
    } );
</script>
```

table1 is generated by loading the page, while table2 is generated by clicking on any row of table1, using Ajax.

upon click or hover, the script adds some classes to tr (table rows) so I can style them (change background color)

the script applies to table1 rows and adds classes, but does not apply to table2 rows!

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the JavaScript code

Comment: You need to put up some more code. Post the script you're referring to.

Comment: Please include the actual table html and the relevent css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These events only apply to elements that exist when the page is loaded.  You need to use "live" events for them to affect the AJAX-loaded table (table2).

For this, you can use jQuery's [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'tr', function() {
         $(this).parents('table').find('tr').each( function( index, element ) {
              $(element).removeClass('selected');
         } );
         $(this).addClass('selected');
         $(this).removeClass('normal');
    });
    $(document).on('hover', 'tr', function() {
         $(this).addClass('highlight');
         $(this).removeClass('normal');
    });
    $(document).on('mouseover', 'tr', function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')){
            $(this).removeClass('highlight');
        }
    });
});
```

Note: Instead of `document`, you can use the highest parent of both tables (as long as it stays in the DOM).

**UPDATE**: The `if($('tr').hasClass('selected')) {` only ran when the DOM loaded.  Put that check inside the event.

P.S. You can combine all those `$( function() {` together.

Comment: thanks for ur reply. please let me know what to use instead of hover & mouseout, when using jquery .on

Comment: @bijibuji: It's the same as what I posted, just change `'click'` to `'hover'` or `'mouseout'`.

Comment: whats the problem?!

<script type="text/javascript">
$( function() {  
$(document).on('click', 'tr', function() {
$(this).parents('table').find('tr').each( function( index, element ) {
$(element).removeClass('selected');
} );
$(this).addClass('selected');
$(this).removeClass('normal');
} );  
$(document).on('hover', 'tr', function() {
$(this).addClass('highlight');
$(this).removeClass('normal');
} ); 
if($('tr').hasClass('selected')) {}
else {
$(document).on('mouseout', 'tr', function() { $(this).addClass('highlight');      $(this).removeClass('normal');
} );    
}
} );
</script>

Comment: @bijibuji: The `if($('tr').hasClass('selected')) {` only gets executed when the page loads.  Check the update to my answer.

Comment: thanks! every thing works well, and just one little strange thing happens. highlight and normal work reverse!!! when I hover on rows they go to normal style and vice versa

Comment: @bijibuji: Glad I could help :-) Check your CSS, and which styles your adding/removing.

Comment: I am sure the styles are correct. this was woring fine and I reviewd my highlight and normal classes, but they are reversed!!! :(

Comment: <tr class="table_row selected highlight"></tr>
<tr class="table_row highlight"></tr>
<tr class="table_row highlight"></tr>

Answer (score 2):

Using the jQuery `.on()` should do the trick: ( removed excess event handlers for document ready)

```
$(function() {
    $('table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
        $(this).siblings('tr').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected').removeClass('normal');
    });
    $('table').on('hover', 'tr', function() {
        $(this).addClass('highlight').removeClass('normal');
    });
    $('table').on('mouseout', 'tr', function() {
        $(this).not(".selected").removeClass('highlight');
    });

});
```

EDIT: Fixed the not selector on mouseout.

Here is a working sample:http://jsfiddle.net/JCbfw/

EDIT: Note that the click code could be this if you wanted it a bit tighter:

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').removeClass('normal').siblings('tr').removeClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: NOTE: This makes the assumption that the second table exists at the start, even though it is not populated. If that is not correct, you would need to change the 'table' to some selector above the tables - or to document in worst case.

Comment: If `table2` is added via AJAX, this won't work.

Comment: `$('table').on('mouseout','tr:not(".selected")').removeClass('highlight');`  You can't do that.

Comment: mouseout does not appear to work. all rows stay highlighted!

Comment: @Rocket - right, fixed that with a bit code.

Answer (score 0):

Not related to your question, it's much better if you put your `hover` behavior into CSS codes:

```
whatever:hover {}
```